# Changing colorbar colour nodes

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am using the demcmap colorbar to colour my filled contour plot as in the documentation here:

http://uk.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/demcmap.html#outputarg_cmap

My question is, how can I shift the limits on the colorbar so that, say, land extends down to -10 rather than the land-sea split at 0, but the overall colour scheme remains the same?

Sorry if the answer is in the actual documentation posted above, but it didn't seem clear to me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you type `colormapeditor` the nodes for the colours can be adjusted as desired